# Barcode in yii2 not showing up

Tags: php, yii2, barcode

I've been using `yii2` advance template these pass few days and I can't seem to work the bar code module that i've installed. I want the bar code to be presented in the view.php of one of my functions but it doesn't show up.

Here is my view.php source code

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'WeatherStation_Model',
        'WeatherStation_Name',
        'WeatherStation_Location',
        'WeatherStation_Status',
        'WeatherStation_Gateway',
        'WeatherStation_Logger',
        'WeatherStation_Number',
        [  
            'attribute' => 'barcode_no',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'filter' => BarcodeGenerator::widget([
                'elementId' => 'barcode-'.$model->barcode_no,
                'value' => $model->barcode_no,
                'type' => 'code128',
                'rectangular' => true,
                 'settings' => [
                     'output' => 'canvas',
                     ],
                ]),
        ], 
        ],
]) ?>
```

And this is the result when i try to execute the view command

[image: Same data being passed, not the barcode image itself]

Comment: Which BarcodeGenerator widget is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change format image:

```
'format' => 'image',
```

And check result.

Comment: tried but still no image of the barcode. Instead of having a value its blank now